# Performing iterative arithmetic over a column in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math, data-science

I am attempting to perform arithmetic on the 'data_d' column.

```
dataframe

data_a        data_b      data_c    data_d
60            0.30786     Discharge 2.31714    
61            0.30792          Rest 2.34857   
121           0.62095          Rest 2.38647    
182           0.93398     Discharge 2.31115    
183           0.93408          Rest 2.34550    
243           1.24711          Rest 2.37162    
304           1.56014     Discharge 2.30855    
305           1.56019          Rest 2.34215    
365           1.87322          Rest 2.36276     
426           2.18630     Discharge 2.30591
```

I want to assign the variables A,B,C into a new column named 'variable'. As shown below.

```
dataframe2

data_a        data_b      data_c    data_d     variable
60            0.30786     Discharge 2.31714    A
61            0.30792          Rest 2.34857    B
121           0.62095          Rest 2.38647    C
182           0.93398     Discharge 2.31115    A
183           0.93408          Rest 2.34550    B
243           1.24711          Rest 2.37162    C
304           1.56014     Discharge 2.30855    A
305           1.56019          Rest 2.34215    B
365           1.87322          Rest 2.36276    C
426           2.18630     Discharge 2.30591    A
```

The script then should perform the following operation iteratively over the entire 'data_d' column.

```
(C - (B-A))
(2.38647 - (2.34857-2.31714))
(2.35504)
...
```

```
dataframe3
     measurement
0    2.35504
1    2.33727
2    2.32916
...  ...
```

And so on.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the `cumsum` to create the `groupby` key , then do `cumcount` with `groupby` `map` the number of count back to letter

```
key = df['data_c'].eq('Discharge').cumsum()
df['variable'] = df.groupby(key).cumcount().map({0:'A',1:'B',2:'C'})
df
Out[61]: 
   data_a   data_b     data_c   data_d variable
0      60  0.30786  Discharge  2.31714        A
1      61  0.30792       Rest  2.34857        B
2     121  0.62095       Rest  2.38647        C
3     182  0.93398  Discharge  2.31115        A
4     183  0.93408       Rest  2.34550        B
5     243  1.24711       Rest  2.37162        C
6     304  1.56014  Discharge  2.30855        A
7     305  1.56019       Rest  2.34215        B
8     365  1.87322       Rest  2.36276        C
9     426  2.18630  Discharge  2.30591        A
```

Then we just need to pivot : here I am using `crosstab`

```
s = pd.crosstab(index=key, columns=df['variable'], values=df['data_d'], aggfunc='sum')
dfout = s.eval('C - (B-A)').to_frame(name = 'measurement')
dfout
Out[69]: 
        measurement
data_c             
1           2.35504
2           2.33727
3           2.32916
4               NaN
```